# Notepad++ Using User-Defined Language to highlight a substring

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I'm working with a programming language without a proper IDE and I'm using notepad++ as my editor.  I've set up a user-defined language and it's working pretty well, but I have a problem in that if you enter a keyword it must match perfectly.  I'll explain what I mean.

If I add '*string*' as a keyword and I enter '*string*' into the text area that it becomes highlighted.

However if I enter '*string(variableName)*' then it doesn't highlight.

If I turn on prefix mode it highlights the whole '*string(variableName)*' when I only want it to highlight '*string*'.

It may be that I just can't do this in notepad++ but I wondered if anyone had come across (and solved) a similar issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even though it has been a while...

If you want the keyword 'string' to be highlighted when typing 'string(variableName)' you need to define '(' as an operator or type 'string (variableName)' [note the blank space!], so that npp recognizes the word boundaries correctly.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **SynWrite** editor, also free, which has fully-customizable lexer editor, with more settings than NP++ UDL.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to add software to my work computer, so I need to make do with what I have.